# React JS - The color of the LI remains the same when I add a new element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have here 2 JS files here (React JS) and a small error. The idea is that this application is an TodoList and an element is created by clicking on the respective button. It works well but every time I add a new element, the color of the li stays the same. It doesn't move after that LI.

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react"
import ItemToDo from "./ItemToDo"
import "./style.scss"

export default function App() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([])
    const [currentMap, setMap] = useState()
    const inputRef = useRef()

    const addElement = () => {
        if (inputRef.current.value === "") {
            alert("Please enter something...")
        } else {
            items.unshift(inputRef.current.value)
            setItems(items)
            console.log(items)
            inputRef.current.value = ""
            updateMap()
        }
    }
    const updateMap = () => {
        setMap(items.map((item, key) => <ItemToDo key={key} item={item} removeElement={() => removeElement(key)} />))
    }
    const removeElement = (index) => {
        delete items[index]
        updateMap()
    }
    const handleKey = (e) => {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            addElement()
        }
    }
    return (
        <>
            <h1>ToDo List</h1>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name here" ref={inputRef} id="elementName" onKeyDown={handleKey} autoFocus />
            <input type="button" value="Add Item" id="submit" onClick={addElement} />
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {currentMap}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

and ItemToDo.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react"

export default function ItemToDo({item, removeElement}) {
    const [color, setColor] = useState(true)
    const setBackground = () => {
        setColor(false)
    }
    return (
        <li style={{backgroundColor: color ? "green" : "red"}}>
            <span>{item}</span>
            <input type="button" value="Delete" onClick={removeElement} />
            <input type="button" value="Done!" onClick={() => setBackground()} />
        </li>
    )
}
```

And I want to fix this bug... Basically if I add a new element the red color stays there.
Thanks in advance for any idea!

Comment: Are you saying that when you click the list item, it doesn't change from green to red?

Comment: mm, not really. it changes..but if I add a new element the color does not stay on that LI.